# jQuery: File dialog not opening in chrome

Tags: jquery

Here is a strange problem in Google chrome:

Following code doesn't open file dialog box after successful AJAX call:

```
    $("#btnUpload").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:"isowner?docid="+currentFolderId+"&isfolder="+currentFolder,
            type:"GET"
        }).done(function(){
            $("#upldFile").click();
        }).error(function(xhr, status, error){alert("errror");
          return false;
        });
    });
```

but following code works if i put `$("#upldFile").click();` out of `done()`

```
    $("#btnUpload").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#upldFile").click();
        $.ajax({
            url:"isowner?docid="+currentFolderId+"&isfolder="+currentFolder,
            type:"GET"
        }).done(function(){

        }).error(function(xhr, status, error){alert("errror");
          return false;
        });
    });
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Is there any specific need to use `click()` inside success block `.done()`?

Comment: Yah it should popop based on the server response.

Comment: what do you get if you `console.log($("#upldFile"))`? Is it just a Chrome issue or all browsers?

Comment: Oh So that is your code for `popup`, sorry I was thought `click()` as event inside success block.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that .done() is called ? If not just add ` `console.log("ajax done");` inside it.

Comment: Its just chrome issue . in FF it works as expected